# jQuery.support is undefined [Break On This Error] if (jQuery.support.positionFixed === undefined) {

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

i am using jquery 1.2.6 min.js,inettuts.js for multiple icons drag and drop functionality in drupal application.I got above error in my application.Icons drag and drop working fine but jQuery.support is undefined error coming in drupal.js.Please any body help to me how to solve this problem.I have tried with jquery 1.3.2 min.js error not coming but icons not drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, this is because `jQuery.support` was [introduced in 1.3](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)

In versions prior to 1.3, [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) was used to browser sniff, rather than feature detect. It has since been depreciated.

jQuery 1.2.6 will celebrate it's [4th birthday next year](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2.6). You should *seriously* consider [upgrading to a newer version](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update).

Comment: thanks  for giving response,can u please tel me hoe to solve my problem with updated jquery

Comment: how to use jQuery.browser to my problem,please explain to me